# Setting unknown property when trying to join table

Tags: element, join

I've successfully joined a table to the elements table, however I can't can't seem to add a property so I can use it?

Getting the error **Setting unknown property when trying to join table**

```
Entry::find()
    ->addSelect(['craft_event_instances.instance_datetime'])
    ->leftJoin('craft_event_instances', '`craft_event_instances`.`entryId` = `elements`.`id`')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a property of an `element` in Craft that does not exists in the field layout, as a behavior or as a public/private attribute in the object. Craft/Yii2 will throw an exception because the property `instance_datetime` probably does not exist.

In order to attach a custom value you have to either create a new `element` or you have to store this information somewhere else.

#### Edit

You could the following as well to fetch your values and store them into a new array

```
$query = Entry::find();
$columns = $query
    ->addSelect('craft_event_instances.instance_datetime')
    ->innerJoin('craft_event_instances', 'craft_event_instances.entryId = elements.id')
    ->createCommand()
    ->queryAll();
$yourCustomValues = [];
foreach($columns as $key => $column){
    $yourCustomValues[$column['id']] = $column['instance_datetime'];
    unset($columns[$key]['instance_datetime']);
}
$elements = $query->populate($columns);
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance, is there anyway I can retrofit the relations table somehow?

Comment: Yes. You can join the table like every other table as well. Not sure where you problem is

Comment: Im just having a hard time wrapping my head around the db design. I have a category field called genre which I want included in the results array

Comment: It depends what you need... I could explain this on Slack or here in the chat or you could create a new question because it doesn't really fit here in my opinion. Your new question is more about the structure of Craft which is quite simple but you need to understand what it joins. But it would be too much to explain in one comment